# Regex - Removing specific characters before the final occurance of @

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

So, I'm trying to remove certain characters [.&@] before the final occurance of an @, but after that final @, those characters should be allowed.

This is what I have so far.

```
string pattern = @"\.|\&|\@(?![^@]+$)|[^a-zA-Z@]";
string input = "username@middle&something.else@company.com";

// input, pattern, replacement
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output: usernamemiddlesomethingelse@companycom

This currently removes all occurances of the specified characters, apart from the final @. I'm not sure how to get this to work, help please?

Comment: Why not split on the '@' character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[.&@]+(?=.*@)
```

Or, equivalent `[.&@]+(?![^@]*$)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJGj6s/1).

**Details**

- `[.&@]+` - 1 or more `.`, `&` or `@` chars
- `(?=.*@)` - followed with any 0+ chars (other than LF) as many as possible and then a `@`.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/8pHQXw):

```
string pattern = @"[.&@]+(?=.*@)";
string input = "username@middle&something.else@company.com";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => usernamemiddlesomethingelse@company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple solution (and alternative to complex regex) using `Substring` and `LastIndexOf`:

```
string pattern = @"[.@&]";
string input = "username@middle&something.else@company.com";

string inputBeforeLastAt = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf('@'));

// input, pattern, replacement
string result = Regex.Replace(inputBeforeLastAt, pattern, string.Empty) + input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('@'));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Try it with [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CV8Boe).

Comment: your output is: `username@middlesomethingelse@company.com`

Comment: Your pattern should be `[.@&]`